# python-scrapy set stats value in extension

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to write a simple scrapy extension-class to send crawler-stats when the spider closes via email. This is what I have so far, which works fine.

```
class SpiderClosedCommit(object):

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ext = cls(crawler.stats)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return ext

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider_stats = self.stats.get_stats(spider)
        # some more code to send an email with stats ...
```

But now I'm trying to figure out how to add a list to the stats with the domains that were scraped. I looked through the docs but I couldn't figure out how the code should look like and where to put it, in the extension or in the spider-class. How can I get access to the scraped domains in the extension class or how can I get access to the stats in the spider-class?

Thanks in advance and all the best

Jacques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. make your extension hook to the [response_received](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.response_received) signal and extract the domain from `response.url`
2. keep a `set()` in your extension with the domains seen
3. when closing the spider, add those domains to`spider_stats` before sending by email